# 4gb File Size Restriction on fat32 External HDD

Tags: 13.10, filesystem, fat32

I have an external 1tb HDD that is formatted in fat32.  I use it to connect to my Blu-ray player, which has a USB port, to watch movies.  Frequently, movie files are over 4gb and will not transfer to the drive from my computer.  The Blu-ray player will only recognize the fat32 file system.  Is there a way to overcome this within Ubuntu?  Perhaps a terminal command that I am not aware of?  As a last resort, can you recommend a program that will split the file in half, transfer it the external HDD, and re-assemble it there?  Any advice will be appreciated.

When I use the split -b command, the second file that it creates is unreadable.  I am perplexed.

Can anyone recommend methods of splitting the file using ffmpeg or mencoder?  I have read about both, but have not been able to do what I need done with them.

Answer (score 1):

No; fat32 only supports 4 GiB files.  If you need larger files you will have to use a different filesystem ( ntfs if you need to share it with Windows, otherwise ext4 ).

Comment: I realize that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try formatting the drive as exFAT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT. No Guarantee it'll work on your Blu-Ray player but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: I'd rather not re-format the drive.

Comment: It's the only option. A larger than 4GiB cannot exist on a FAT32 partition. If you have a flash drive you can try formatting that as exFAT as a test before unnecessarily formatting your 1TB.

Comment: The Blu-ray player will not recognize exFAT, NTFS or EXT.  Dang.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with several terminal methods, I decided to install mkvmerge.  I managed to basically accomplish what I needed with it.  Thank you to everyone who gave me advice.